# detect input value change maded by a non-controlled by me function in pure JS

Tags: javascript, onchange

Is possible to detect an input value change maded by a non-controlled by me function?

I mean that I don't know the function that changes the input value, so in what way can I detect it?

I've tried:

```
myInput.onchange = function(){...}
```

or

```
myInput.addEventListener('change',function(){...})
```

but do nor work...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gu5gtjp/) to do tries

Comment: add an event listener for the 'change' event

Comment: xshirase I've tried but does not work

Comment: Do you control the code though? Can you change the input to a span instead?

Comment: @Sebas no, I can't... however can you explan why?

Comment: I was thinking about using the MutationObserver object, but it doesn't work with input elements (you need a content node such as a span to trigger html change). You could always use the old deprecated dom level 2 events DOMAttrChanged or similar... It might work, but raise some warnings in your console :) Is it production code?

Comment: actually I can use a <td>..